# Problema de orden de columnas al intentar mostrar DataFrame en el html mediante el template

Tags: python, pandas, flask, dataframe, ordenamiento

tengo un problema con el orden en el que me figuran los datos que extraigo de un excel, con Pandas en un dataframe.

**Este sería el .csv**

```
Id,Type,Job Name,User Name,Date,Time,Print Pages,Color Pages
1,Print(Network),"Brother MFC-L8900CDW series","molazar",18/02/2020,11:08:28,?,?
2,Print(Network),"Brother MFC-L8900CDW series","molazar",18/02/2020,11:09:18,1,0
3,Print(Network),"CCF_000002.pdf","molazar",18/02/2020,15:03:24,1,0
4,Print(Network),"CCF_000002.pdf","molazar",18/02/2020,15:03:42,1,0
5,Print(Network),"CCF_000002.pdf","molazar",18/02/2020,15:04:06,1,0
6,Print(Network),"CCF_000002.pdf","molazar",18/02/2020,15:04:29,1,1
7,Print(Network),"CCF_000002.pdf","molazar",18/02/2020,15:05:04,0,0
8,Copy,-,-,18/02/2020,15:05:22,1,1
```

**excelimport.py**

```
import pandas as pd

def datos():
    data = pd.read_csv('excel.csv', header = 1)
    return data

def mostrar():
    df = pd.DataFrame(datos)
    return datos
```

**index.py** Cabe destacar que en html obviamente utilizo las pos1, pos2, etc para identificar las celdas.

```
@app.route('/registro')
def registro():

    data = excelimport.datos()

    celda1 = data.iloc[:, 0]
    celda2 = data.iloc[:, 1]
    celda3 = data.iloc[:, 2] 
    celda4 = data.iloc[:, 3]
    celda5 = data.iloc[:, 4]
    celda6 = data.iloc[:, 5]
    celda7 = data.iloc[:, 6]
    celda8 = data.iloc[:, 7]

    return render_template('registro.html', pos1 = celda1, 
                                            pos2 = celda2,
                                            pos3 = celda3,
                                            pos4 = celda4,
                                            pos5 = celda5,
                                            pos6 = celda6,
                                            pos7 = celda7,
                                            pos8 = celda8,
                                            )
```

**Esta es la template registro.html a la que estoy derivando los datos que llegan del Dataframe al index.py**

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}

{% block content %}

<div class="jumbotron">
  <body>
    <div class="texto"></div>

    <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
      <div class="spinner-border spinner-border-sm" role="status">
        <span class="sr-only"></span>
      </div>&nbsp;&nbsp;Desarrollo en proceso <b>(95%)</b>
    </div>
    <table class="egt">
    <span class="badge badge-primary">Registro de impresiones</span>
    <br>
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">
            <b>ID</b></th>
        <th><b>Tipo</b></th>
        <th><b>Archivo</b></th>
        <th><b>Usuario</b></th>
        <th><b>Fecha</b></th>
        <th><b>Hora</b></th>
        <th><b>Hojas</b></th>
        <th><b>Color</b></th>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>{{ pos1 }}</td>   
        <td>{{ pos2 }}</td>  
        <td>{{ pos3 }}</td>    
        <td>{{ pos4 }}</td>
        <td>{{ pos5 }}</td>
        <td>{{ pos6 }}</td> 
        <td>{{ pos7 }}</td>
        <td>{{ pos8 }}</td>   
      </tr>

  </body>
</div>

{% endblock %}
```

Resultado que estoy teniendo:
[image: Resultado]

Lo estoy montando en Flask y está echo en Pandas el import. Claramente como se vé están los datos desordenados y precisaría ordenarlos, no sé si existe otra biblioteca para .csv pero no entiendo el por qué al deosrden, en teoría, de hecho ejecutando el excel sin el dataframe lo lee completamente en la consola.

Gracias!

Comment: Puedes pasar el DataFrame de muchas formas, pero lo importante es como lo usas en el template(que no muestras) ¿Usas Jinja  para iterar sobre las columnas?

Comment: @FJSevilla ahí agregué el template (registro.html). No, no utilicé jina, por el momento Pandas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ten en cuenta que celda1, celda2, etc son columnas y son esas columnas las que usas al completo como contenido para una sola celda.

En vez de pasar columnas pasa un iterable con las filas del dataframe, luego en el template vía Jinja iteras sobre el iterable con las filas, generando un `tr` por cada una y luego sobre cada fila y creas un `td` por cada valor:

**`index.py`**

```
@app.route('/registro')
def registro():    
    data = excelimport.datos()
    return render_template('registro.html', data_rows=data.to_numpy())
```

`registro.html`

```
{% block content %}
<div class="jumbotron">
   <body>
      <div class="texto"></div>
      <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
         <div class="spinner-border spinner-border-sm" role="status">
            <span class="sr-only"></span>
         </div>
         &nbsp;&nbsp;Desarrollo en proceso <b>(95%)</b>
      </div>
      <table class="egt">
      <span class="badge badge-primary">Registro de impresiones</span>
      <br>
      <tr>
         <th scope="row">
            <b>ID</b>
         </th>
         <th><b>Tipo</b></th>
         <th><b>Archivo</b></th>
         <th><b>Usuario</b></th>
         <th><b>Fecha</b></th>
         <th><b>Hora</b></th>
         <th><b>Hojas</b></th>
         <th><b>Color</b></th>
      </tr>
      {% for row in data_rows %}
      <tr>
         {% for  col in row %}
         <td>{{ col }}</td>
         {% endfor %}
      </tr>
      {% endfor %}
   </body>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Que para tu ejemplo, una vez renderizado el template quedaría:

```html
<html>
   <head>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div class="jumbotron">
         <div class="texto"></div>
         <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
            <div class="spinner-border spinner-border-sm" role="status">
               <span class="sr-only"></span>
            </div>
            &nbsp;&nbsp;Desarrollo en proceso <b>(95%)</b>
         </div>
         <span class="badge badge-primary">Registro de impresiones</span><br>
         <table class="egt">
            <tbody>
               <tr>
                  <th scope="row">
                     <b>ID</b>
                  </th>
                  <th><b>Tipo</b></th>
                  <th><b>Archivo</b></th>
                  <th><b>Usuario</b></th>
                  <th><b>Fecha</b></th>
                  <th><b>Hora</b></th>
                  <th><b>Hojas</b></th>
                  <th><b>Color</b></th>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                  <td>2</td>
                  <td>Print(Network)</td>
                  <td>Brother MFC-L8900CDW series</td>
                  <td>molazar</td>
                  <td>18/02/2020</td>
                  <td>11:09:18</td>
                  <td>1</td>
                  <td>0</td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                  <td>3</td>
                  <td>Print(Network)</td>
                  <td>CCF_000002.pdf</td>
                  <td>molazar</td>
                  <td>18/02/2020</td>
                  <td>15:03:24</td>
                  <td>1</td>
                  <td>0</td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                  <td>4</td>
                  <td>Print(Network)</td>
                  <td>CCF_000002.pdf</td>
                  <td>molazar</td>
                  <td>18/02/2020</td>
                  <td>15:03:42</td>
                  <td>1</td>
                  <td>0</td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                  <td>5</td>
                  <td>Print(Network)</td>
                  <td>CCF_000002.pdf</td>
                  <td>molazar</td>
                  <td>18/02/2020</td>
                  <td>15:04:06</td>
                  <td>1</td>
                  <td>0</td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                  <td>6</td>
                  <td>Print(Network)</td>
                  <td>CCF_000002.pdf</td>
                  <td>molazar</td>
                  <td>18/02/2020</td>
                  <td>15:04:29</td>
                  <td>1</td>
                  <td>1</td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                  <td>7</td>
                  <td>Print(Network)</td>
                  <td>CCF_000002.pdf</td>
                  <td>molazar</td>
                  <td>18/02/2020</td>
                  <td>15:05:04</td>
                  <td>0</td>
                  <td>0</td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                  <td>8</td>
                  <td>Copy</td>
                  <td>-</td>
                  <td>-</td>
                  <td>18/02/2020</td>
                  <td>15:05:22</td>
                  <td>1</td>
                  <td>1</td>
               </tr>
            </tbody>
         </table>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Una tabla no muy bonita, pero cada dato en su sitio.

Otra opción es que uses directamente [`pandas.DataFrame.to_html()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_html.html), te da algo menos de control pero es muy simple de usar, además de permitir exportar los estilos.

Comment: muchisimas gracias en serio! @FJSevilla

Comment: consulta, en el caso que quiera sumar el contenido de la columna "Print Pages" y tener un resultado como lo haría en este Dataframe? Al igual que 2 columnas

Answer (score 0):

En el caso de querer sumar columnas utilizo df aunque no tengo devolución

```
def mostrar():
    df = pd.DataFrame(datos)
    df['Resutlado'] = df['Print Pages'] + df['Color Pages']
    return datos
```